# How to let the red UIView cover the whole screen, expect from the navigation bar & status bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, landscape

When I rotate the iPhone, I set the redview to this :
Also, I set the rootViewController to hidden already...

```
[appDelegate.myRootViewController.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
redView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
```

But seems that the tabbarcontroller still cover the redView,ow can I resolve it? Thank you.
(I also try to set the tabbarcontroller's view to other position, but the redview still can't show in the whole screen, thank you.[image])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked what index the tabbar has, it seems like the tabbar has a higher index in the view-hierachy than the redview.